# Moving and merging reporting server instances

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reportserver

I have a machine where we have SSRS and SQL Server running, Currently we use SSRS and configured it to use localhost SQL Server hosted ReportServer and ReportServertempdb.

Now we need decomission this machine and move the reports to a brand new machine. Now the brand new machine does not have SQL Server, but we have another SQL Server which has 2 pre-existing databases: ReportServer and ReportServertempdb which are already being used by another SSRS instance. Now we are planning to use them for our to-be-moved SSRS instance as well.

Is it possible for multiple SSRS instance to use same ReportServer and ReportServertempdb? If yes how do you merge these? There are certain conflicting values. For example in the ReportServer DB in the table "ConfigurationInfo", SystemReportTimeout is 1800 for my current instance, but on my proposed instance value is -1. How to tackle this during a merge? I have many conflicting records in both ReportServer databases.

Answer (score 3):

You can create several databases on your machine, each DB + TempDB for one instance. But it is not possible to share DB + TempDB for two different instances.

Even if this would work in theory, you will get a lot of problems with sync. caches tables, security tokens, etc.

Edit: So imho backup your databases and restore on a different name. Then you SSRS configration manager to connect to a existing database.
If you use security tokens for those DB's, make sure your have the .snk file.

Answer (score 2):

Though you can share RS databases across multiple instances, you cannot merge two different ones to the same one. Unfortunately we cannot even rename RS databases as they are considered system databases. Your best bet would be to see if you can host your databases on another SQL instance on the same server or redeploy your reports on the new server.
For additional information you can refer to the following links:
Scaleout deployment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157293(v=SQL.90).aspx

Managing RS DBs:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156421%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159093.aspx